# centralising the table contents

Tags: tables

could anyone help me to centralise the table using this code, please

```
\usepackage {ctable}
\begin{tabular}{llr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{steady-state error} \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2}
    initial gains & tuned gains & mass uncertainty \\
    \midrule
    11 & 0.27 & 5 \\
    21 & 0.47 & 10 \\
    43 & 0.93 & 20 \\
    107.7 & 2.40 & 50 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: What do you want to centre? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know this package `ctable`, but you can centre tables by putting them in a `\begin{center}\end{center}` or inside a floating `table` environment together with `\centering`. For centring inside the columns you have to use the `c` qualifier. Or you use the nice `S` column of `siunitx`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{caption}\label{tab:label}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.1]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.0]}  
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{steady-state error} \\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2}
        {initial gains} & {tuned gains} & {mass uncertainty} \\
        \midrule
        11 & 0.27 & 5 \\
        21 & 0.47 & 10 \\
        43 & 0.93 & 20 \\
        107.7 & 2.40 & 50 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

I just read the really easy documentation of `ctable`. You have not been using its main command `\ctable` in your code. The centring seems to be default here. If you do not want it, just put `left` or `right` as an option to it.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\ctable[%
    caption=caption,
    label=tab:label
    ]
    {S[table-format=3.1]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.0]}
    {}
    {%
        \FL
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{steady-state error} \\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2}
        {initial gains} & {tuned gains} & {mass uncertainty}
        \ML
        11 & 0.27 & 5 \\
        21 & 0.47 & 10 \\
        43 & 0.93 & 20 \\
        107.7 & 2.40 & 50 
        \LL
    }
\end{document}
```

---

Both above codes result in the same image (or very similar).